# Is the Gallery app scanning my photos?

Tags: samsung

The Gallery app is now using face recognition on my images. Is this sending my images to the Samsung server? Is Samsung stealing my pictures and uploaded them to their server? How do I uninstall this app?

Here is the settings view per request below.

[image]

Comment: Answer edited check

Answer (score 0):

It will **NOT** send any picture to server, it is feature to easy you task in contacts and social platforms but some times quite annoying.
System apps cannot be uninstalled on **Non-Rooted** phone.
So to uninstall app you need to root your phone and use any other third party app manager. However **rooting voids your warranty** , as far I am aware of Samsung.
And there must be option to turn off Face Recognition.
Solution:-

1. Go in gallery
2. Open a picture
3. Open drop down /Tap menu key/ open setting
4. Tap on facetag
5. Turn it off.

Comment: I don't have that option.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Which phone are you using?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts By tapping menu key , there should be option of settings on long pressing on picture

Comment: There isn't that option. It has to be sending that information to the server. It's tagging everything.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Is there any yellow box around image?

Comment: no there is not